# XML Syntaxhighlight highlights elements in CDATA

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting, xml

If you manually declare code to be XML, code within CDATA is still highlighted, even though it should be treated as text.

Example:

```xml
<element test="test">
      <![CDATA[<font size="2"><ul><li><p align="justify">Lorem ipsum</p></li></ul></font>]]>
</element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's how google-code-prettify works

> http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html#xhtml

But if you need to disable the highlighting, you might need to use `languge: none` syntax.

```
<!-- language: none -->

    <![CDATA[<font size="2"><ul><li><p align="justify">Lorem ipsum</p></li></ul></font>]]>
```

Comment: For JavaScript, that's fine. For XML, that's not. CDATA text should be treated normally.